# Inconsistent highlighting on selected UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in which I need to programmatically select a cell if the data model says that the cell represents the selected choice in a list of items. I do this when I'm configuring the `UITableViewCell`:

```
if (group == self.theCase.assignedGroup) {
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
} else {
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

I am seeing very odd behavior with this. If the first row of the tableview is the one that should be selected, the cell doesn't highlight its background properly. However, if the second row is the one that should be selected, it works as it's supposed to (screenshots at the end).

**UPDATE**: It could have something to do with the fact that I am loading data for the table asynchronously, and while the data is loading I show a different kind of cell with a progress indicator in that first row. Here's the table view data source code that's handling this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.hasMorePages) {
        return self.groups.count + 1;
    }
    return self.groups.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (indexPath.row < self.groups.count) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DSAssignCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DSLoadingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self configureLoadingCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DSGroup *group = self.groups[indexPath.row];
    if (group == self.theCase.assignedGroup) {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    } else {
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = group.name;
    cell.tag = kDataCellTag;
}

- (void)configureLoadingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
           forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    if ([cell viewWithTag:kActivityIndicatorTag]) {
        activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[cell viewWithTag:kActivityIndicatorTag];
    } else {
        activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        activityIndicator.center = cell.center;
        activityIndicator.tag = kActivityIndicatorTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:activityIndicator];
    }
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    cell.tag = kLoadingCellTag;
}
```

**UPDATE** As requested, here is the code that handles the asynchronous loading of the group & agent data from the web service:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self resetData];
    [self loadData];
}

- (void)resetData
{
    self.currentPage = 0;
    self.hasMorePages = YES;
    self.groups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kGroupsPerPage];
    self.agents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kAgentsPerPage];
}

- (void)loadData
{
    if (self.showingGroups) {
        [DSGroup fetchGroupsOnPage:self.currentPage + 1 perPage:kGroupsPerPage success:^(NSArray *groups, NSDictionary *links, NSNumber *totalEntries) {
            [self.groups addObjectsFromArray:groups];
            [self didLoadDataPage:(links[@"next"] != [NSNull null])];
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            [self showAlert:@"Could not load groups. Please try again later." withError:error];
        }];
    } else {
        [DSUser fetchUsersOnPage:self.currentPage + 1 perPage:kAgentsPerPage success:^(NSArray *users, NSDictionary *links, NSNumber *totalEntries) {
            [self.agents addObjectsFromArray:users];
            [self didLoadDataPage:(links[@"next"] != [NSNull null])];
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            [self showAlert:@"Could not load users. Please try again later." withError:error];
        }];
    }    
}

- (void)didLoadDataPage:(BOOL)hasMorePages
{
    self.hasMorePages = hasMorePages;
    self.currentPage++;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Here's a screenshot of trying to select (and highlight) the first row, which is wrong (no gray background):
[image: Trying to select row 0]

Here's a screenshot of trying to select (and highlight) the second row, which is correct:
[image: [Trying to select row 1]

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: Not enough code here - where are you doing this configuration ? My best guess is that it's something to do with your dequeuing of cells.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I added the `UITableView` dataSource methods.

Comment: So are you saying that the first cell (the incorrect one) is an instance of DSAssignCell or DSLoadingCell ?

Comment: On initial load of the page it's a DSLoadingCell, but then once the data is loaded, I reload the tableview and it should then be a DSAssignCell.

Comment: Right - what I mean is is the incorrect cell actually just the DSLoadingCell ?

Comment: No, it looks like the reuse identifiers are correct. I added some logging to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and this is what I see: https://gist.github.com/jamieforrest/20256b9b8da04d4610d2

Comment: Where/how are you populating the "groups" array?  Could you post that code here?

Comment: And are you reloading the table within the same block/method in which you're loading your table asynchronously?  If you could post more code here, I think we could be more helpful.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Thanks for taking a look. Yes, I reload the table view after loading the data. Take a look at the second update above--I included the async data loading code.

Comment: Since the proper title's showing up when you configure that first cell, the group at self.groups[indexPath.row] is clearly the proper group but since it's not being selected, the if-statement isn't executing properly.  So it could be one of two things: 1. The cell isn't selectable/the selection style isn't set for some reason (I suggest doing so explicitly in the "DSAssignCell" case in cellForRowAtIndexPath:) or 2. since group is the proper group, there might be a problem with the way you're assigning self.theCase.assignedGroup.  How are you assigning self.theCase.assignedGroup?

Comment: Actually the if statement is working properly. When I step through the code it evaluates as expected. And you can see in the screenshots that the textLabel is getting selected properly--it's just the background of the cell that isn't changing.

Comment: I also tried explicitly changing the cell's selection style in cellForRowAtIndexPath but it didn't help. self.theCase.assignedGroup is getting set in the prior view controller when the case gets displayed in a list view. @LyndseyScott thanks for your continued help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to fix this using the built-in selection styles of `UITableViewCell`, but subclassing it and overriding `setSelected:animated` fixed it:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

     self.contentView.backgroundColor = selected ? [UIColor grayColor] : [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```